# Mainnet node sync really slowly with 12 tb seagate external hdd says data rate is 6gb/s

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, synchronization, bitcoin-cli, performance

Hi my node is syncing really slowly I have the datadir in an external hard drive connected through usb. Says the data rate for this seagate 12TB is 6Gb/s but the syncing is slow in comparison to when I have synced nodes in the past with internal nvme drives but 2TB is low so I am moving up to a larger hard drive and went with the external.

Any thoughts or someone who experienced similar? Even when communicating with RPC it is slower than normal I thought maybe it was because it was syncing but I am beginning to question it. Thanks for whatever input.

Also my internet is 1gbps upload download and it is connected through ethernet did a speed test to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard disk drives have been known to sync much slower than SSDs due to their slower read/write speed and higher latency. Even a SATA (non-NVMe) SSD will do a much better job. This also applies to RPC calls that need to read from the disk.

6 Gb/s (768 MB/s) is just the theoretical limit of the interface your drive is connected through, no hard disk drive can actually read or write at this speed.

Comment: ahh damn thats kind of what I was starting to realize oh well, thanks

Comment: also if have any memory recommendations seems hard to find larger SSDs like 8TB+ that aren't insanely expensive am thinking about combining nvme's somehow

Comment: Have you considered combining a HDD with a smaller SSD for optional fast storage? The Bitcoin blockchain is currently a little over 500 GB, so even just a 1 TB drive will last you for some time.

Comment: No but i will, I ran out of space before thats why I was trying the HDD but I might have messed up the configuration somehow or double synced somehow

Comment: was also an ethereum and btc node on the same computer neither are fully synced right now but i think like 80% each its about 961G I have 3TB so maybe I can use them with the HDD

Comment: Increasing the database cache can dramatically speed up synchronization, especially on disks with slow I/O like spinning ones.